# How i can change style in primefaces component?

Tags: css, primefaces

How i can change style in [primeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) panel?
this is my tag

```
<p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

...and if you want to use a CSS class, you must use `styleClass` attribute (and not `class` as in HTML).

```
<p:panel styleClass="myTastyStyle">
```

with CSS :)

```
.myTastyStyle {
  background: pink;
  color: lime;
}
```